# Github get summary of contributions to project

Tags: github

Is there a way to get a summary of your contributions to a specific project on GitHub? For example:

- Number of commits
- Number of PR's
- Number of issues opened.

Basically what you can see in your contributions overview on your profile, but right now you have to scroll through it and press on "Show more activity" to see more contributions.

Answer (score 3):

### Go to a specific project and click on the ***Insights*** tab

[image: tabs on a specific project on github]

#### On side panel click on Contributors to know your position and total commits to that project

[image: go to contributors]

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem partially. This will not work for bigger projects with many contributors, since the "contributor" page only shows the top 100. I upvoted, but for the reasons above I cannot accept it as answer.